# Interchange of summation of measures and integral

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I want to show: If $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of measures on $X$ and $\mu=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu_n$ and $f\colon X\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a measurable function. Then $f$ is $\mu$ integrable if and only if

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_X |f|\mathrm{d}\mu_n < \infty $. It then follows that $\int_X f\mathrm{d}\mu =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_X f\mathrm{d}\mu_n$.

Firstly, I stated that there is a sequence of step functions $(S_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ which convergence p.w. to $f$.

I begin with $\int_X f \sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu_n = \sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i \sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu_n(X_i)$ by definition of the integral of a step function. Now i know that the sum of measure converges, which also means that it converges absolutely and I can interchange the double sum.

It then follows that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_i\mu_n(X_i)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i \mu_n(X_i)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_x f\mathrm{d}\mu_n$

I have my doubts that this is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_n$ states that $\mu(A)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_n(A)$ for every measurable set $A$.

Based on that it can be shown that: $$\int sd\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int sd\mu_n$$ for any nonnegative measurable function $s$ that has finite image.

Now let $g$ be a nonnegative measurable function. If $s$ is a function as described above with $s\leq g$ then $\int sd\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int sd\mu_n\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int gd\mu_n$ and on base of the definition of $\int gd\mu$ we conclude that: $$\int gd\mu\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int gd\mu_n$$

Now we will prove that for every $m$ we have $\int gd\mu\geq\sum_{n=1}^m\int gd\mu_n$ and consequently: $$\int gd\mu\geq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int gd\mu_n$$

If $\sum_{n=1}^m\int gd\mu_n=\infty$ then $\int gd\mu_k=\infty$ for some index $k\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ and consequently $\int gd\mu=\infty$ since $\mu\geq\mu_k$.

If $\sum_{n=1}^m\int gd\mu_n<\infty$ then for $\epsilon>0$ we can find a function $s$ as described above with $\sum_{n=1}^m\int sd\mu_n\geq\sum_{n=1}^m\int gd\mu_n-\epsilon$ and consequently $\int gd\mu\geq\sum_{n=1}^m\int gd\mu_n-\epsilon$.

Proved is now that: $$\int gd\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int gd\mu_n$$ for nonnegative measurable functions $g$.

This can be applied on $g:=|f|$ and gives the result you want: $$f\text{ is }\mu\text{-integrable iff }\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int |f|d\mu_n<\infty$$

---

**edit** to clarify.

Let $s$ be a nonnegative measurable function $s$ that has finite image. That means that we can write: $$s=\sum_{i=1}^ma_i1_{B_i}$$ where $a_i\geq0$ and the $B_i$ are measurable disjoint and covering sets.

Then: $$\begin{aligned}\int sd\mu & =\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{n}\mu\left(B_{i}\right)\\
 & =\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{n}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_{n}\left(B_{i}\right)\\
 & =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{n}\mu_{n}\left(B_{i}\right)\\
 & =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int sd\mu_{n}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: How would you show the case for a non-negative measurable function (3rd line where you stated "Based on that it can be shown")? Also the interchange of sum and integral should be valid for $f$ arbitrary just being measurable. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I have added something.

Comment: I added something. The answer shows that the interchange is valid for nonnegative measurable functions. If $f$ is a measurable function and its integral is defined then it works for $f_+$ and $f_-$ and consequently also for $f=f_+-f_-$.

Comment: Thank you! How do you justify the interchange of the double sum? $\sum_i^\infty a_i \sum_j^\infty b_j $ is not equal to $\sum_i^\infty \sum_j^\infty a_ib_j$. Not even for the finite case.

Comment: By the fact that all terms are nonnegative. Then interchanging is okay.

Comment: I understand, what if two of the sums where infinite and non-negative, couldn't you interchange then, too?

Comment: Yes. If $a_{ij}\in[0,+\infty]$ for all $i,j$ then $\sum_{i\in I}\sum_{j\in J}a_{ij}=\sum_{j\in J}\sum_{i\in I}a_{ij}$ whenever $I,J$ are countable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68322/discussion-between-epsilondelta-and-drhab).